# How to input Robin boundary conditions for nonstandard Laplace equation?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

What is the correct way to input these boundary conditions for the following nonstandard Laplace equation, whose coefficients of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$ term are not the same?

$$\epsilon^2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}=1$$

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}=0,\,\,\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{y=0}=0,\,\left.u=-2n\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{y=1},\,\left.u=-2\epsilon n\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=1}$$
[image]

Here is my try

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
xmax = 1; ymax = 1;

epsilon = 0.5; n=0.1;

Ω := Rectangle[{0, 0}, {xmax, ymax}];

nv1 = NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
nv2 = NeumannValue[0, y == 0];
nv3 = NeumannValue[-n*epsilon*u[x, y], x == xmax];
nv4 = NeumannValue[-n*u[x, y], y == ymax];

sol = NDSolve[{epsilon^2*D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 1 + nv1 + nv2 + nv3 + nv4}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

```
c = -{{eps^2, 0}, {0, 1}} /. eps -> epsilon;
op = Div[c.Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 
    1 - NeumannValue[u[x, y], x == xmax || y == ymax]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

You'd need to think about the signs. (Do you really want `c` to be positive). The point is you need to fit your equation into the coefficient form for PDEs for the finite element solver to work. Have a look at how the coefficients of the PDE are related to the coefficients in the `NeumannValue`. It's important to understand that the coefficients of the PDE are not independent of the coefficients of the `NeumannValue`. You can find more information in the section [Partial Differential Equations and Boundary Conditions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html) of the documentation. As an alternative the details section of the reference page for [NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) has additional information.

**Update:**

Let's assume your equation is:

$$\nabla\cdot (-c \nabla u) - 1=0$$

this *implies* that the Neumann/Robin operator is:

$$n \cdot (c \nabla u)=g + q u$$

In an initial update I miss read the boundary condition. Because there is an $\epsilon$ and not an $\epsilon^2$ in one of the boundary conditions we model the Robin condition by using `NeumannValue` one on each side.

```
a = 1/2; b = 1;
epsilon = a/b; n = 1/10;
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {xmax = 2 b, ymax = 2 a}];
c = -{{epsilon^2, 0}, {0, 1}};
op = Div[c.Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 1;
g = 0; q = 1/(2 n);
solFEM = NDSolveValue[{op == -NeumannValue[g + epsilon*q*u[x, y], 
        x == xmax] - NeumannValue[g + q*u[x, y], y == ymax]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
Plot3D[solFEM[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
```

[image]

This result agrees with the FDM version by @xzczd once PDE coefficients are made to match. Note that this approach, although it requires a bit of thought, needs much less code than the FDM version.

Comparison with FDM version:

```
With[{u = u[x, y]}, eq = epsilon^2 D[u, x, x] + D[u, y, y] == -1;
 {bc@x, bc@y} = {{D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
    u == -2 epsilon n D[u, x] /. x -> xmax}, {D[u, y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
    u == -2 n D[u, y] /. y -> ymax}};]
```

Gives:

```
Plot3D[solFEM[x, y] - sol[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you. Is there otherway (`NDSolve`) to solve this problem without using `FEM`?

Comment: Not directly, `NDSolve` will use the FEM for elliptic PDEs. You could, however, code your own finite difference with `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`; but I think it should be possible to solve this with FEM. What are your concerns?

Comment: My main concern is the sign with `c`.  I read the documentation and was unable to grasp it. Is it the same as multiplying the left hand of the PDE by a negative sign? or you are having `c` with a negative sign because of the robin boundary conditions?

Comment: Do you have a model problem to which you happen to have the solution?

Comment: Not exactly the same but a close one. https://www.dropbox.com/s/amvhn5xdq49lmir/HIGH%20ORDER%20BOUNDARY%20CONDITIONS%20FOR%20GASEOUS%20FLOWS%20IN%20RECTANGULAR%20MICRODUCTS.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I think, $q=1/(2n)$, then we can have the correct boundary condition.

Comment: OK, I fixed the sign.

Comment: Where is the $\epsilon$ in the boundary condition? or I am missing something?

Comment: @xzczd, see update thanks.

Comment: I agree `NDSolve`-based solution is much conciser than FDM solution. Maybe an automatic analyser can be created (at least for Neumann b.c. in regular domain), given the manual analysing is so error-prone?

Comment: @xzczd, it's not immediately clear to me how one would do that, so it would requite some thought. Or, perhaps you have an idea?

Comment: @user21 I still think that the results of the two methods doesn't match.

Comment: @xzczd Can you please share again your FEM attempt, which u shared as a comment?

Comment: @zhk, make sure the PDEs match.

Comment: Er…for example `epsilon = 0.5; n = 1/10;c = {{coe@1, 0}, {0, coe@2}}; With[{u = u[x, y]}, eq@1 = epsilon^2 D[u, x, x] + D[u, y, y] == -1; 
 eq@2 = Div[-c.Grad[u, {x, y}], {x, y}] == f;
 {bcx@1, bcx@2} = {u == -2 epsilon n D[u, x], {1, 0}.(c.Grad[u, {x, y}]) == q@1 u} /. x -> xmax; {bcy@1, bcy@2} = {u == -2 n D[u, y], {0, 1}.(c.Grad[u, {x, y}]) == q@2 u} /. y -> ymax;];FindInstance[Flatten[(Reap@Collect[Subtract @@ #@1 - k@# Subtract @@ #@2, _[x | xmax, y | ymax], Sow])[[-1,1]] & /@ {eq, bcx, bcy}] == 0 // Thread, Flatten@{{#@1, #@2} & /@ {coe, q}, k /@ {eq, bcx, bcy}, f}]`…

Comment: …Of course it's still crude and to make it general enough, much more work is needed.

Comment: @user21 I'm facing this issue, `u[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[solFEM][x, y], tw[y_?NumericQ] := (D[u[x, y], x] /. x -> 0.0); Plot[tw[y], {y, 0, ymax}]`. Isn't zero in the domain? Please have a look!

Comment: @zhk, that's not valid input.

Comment: @zhk, `tw[y_?NumericQ] = With[{dd = Derivative[1, 0][solFEM][0, y]}, dd];
Plot[tw[y], {y, 0, ymax}]` looks good to me.

Comment: @user21 Thank you.

Comment: @zhk, I think it's better to ask a new question. I can not look at this.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add a solution based on finite difference method (FDM). The advantage of this solution is we don't need to manually transform the equation to any *standard* form. I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equation.

```
xmax = 1; ymax = 1;
epsilon = 0.5; n = 0.1;
With[{u = u[x, y]},
 eq = epsilon^2 D[u, x, x] + D[u, y, y] == 1;
 {bc@x, bc@y} = {{D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, u == -2 epsilon n D[u, x] /. x -> xmax}, 
                 {D[u, y] == 0 /. y -> 0, u == -2 n D[u, y] /. y -> ymax}};]
domain@x = {0, xmax};
domain@y = {0, ymax};
points@x = 25;
points@y = 25;
difforder = 4;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, y};
var = Outer[u, grid@x, grid@y] // Flatten;

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x, y], grid /@ {x, y}, difforder];
removeredundance = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = removeredundance /@ removeredundance@ptoafunc@eq;
aebc@x = removeredundance /@ ptoafunc@bc@x;
aebc@y = ptoafunc@bc@y;
solrule = Solve[{ae, aebc@x, aebc@y} // Flatten, var][[1]];
solpoints = N@solrule /. (u[x_, y_] -> value_) :> {x, y, value};
sol = Interpolation[solpoints]

(* The following is an alternative method for obtaining sol,
   it's more challenging to understand, but more efficient. *)
(*
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[{ae, aebc@x, aebc@y} // Flatten, var];
sollst = LinearSolve[m, -b];
sol = ListInterpolation[ArrayReshape[sollst, {points@x, points@y}], domain /@ {x, y}]
 *)
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Update

If you still feel confused about `removeredundance`, the followings are 2 alternatives that don't require you to remove equations from the system:

```
fullsys = Flatten@ptoafunc@{eq, bc@x, bc@y};

(* Alternative 1: *)

lSSolve[obj_List, constr___, x_, opt : OptionsPattern[FindMinimum]] := 
 FindMinimum[{1/2 obj^2 // Total, constr}, x, opt]
lSSolve[obj_, rest__] := lSSolve[{obj}, rest]

solrule = Last@
    lSSolve[Subtract @@@ fullsys, var]; // AbsoluteTiming

solpoints = N@solrule /. (u[x_, y_] -> value_) :> {x, y, value};
sol = Interpolation[solpoints]

(* Alternative 2: *)

{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[fullsys, var];

sollst = LeastSquares[m, -b]; // AbsoluteTiming
sol = ListInterpolation[ArrayReshape[sollst, {points@x, points@y}], domain /@ {x, y}]
```

You can check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173813/1871) to learn more about `lSSolve`.

---

## Update 2

With my [`allowfemdbc`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268449/1871) we can use `FiniteElement` method without manually setting up `NeumannValue`:

```
solfem = allowfemdbc@NDSolveValue[{eq, bc /@ {x, y}}, 
                                  u, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}];

Plot3D[solfem[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
```

The solution looks the same as above, so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: Why the difference in results between FEM and FDM? try this please `Plot[sol[0, y], {y, 0, ymax}]` for both.

Comment: @zhk ……I think user21 has made a mistake when deducing $c$. I've commented below his answer.

Comment: But if we compare the FDM results with this paper
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amvhn5xdq49lmir/HIGH%20ORDER%20BOUNDARY%20CONDITIONS%20FOR%20GASEOUS%20FLOWS%20IN%20RECTANGULAR%20MICRODUCTS.pdf?dl=0

Both looks different. To get the same type of behaviour we need to have `-sol[0,y]`.

Comment: @zhk Did you notice the right hand side of the equation in the paper is `-1`?

Comment: Oh yes but the velocity potential cannot be negative overhere. I think something wrong with my PDE.

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks dear you made me to rethink my equation.

Answer (score 1):

Version 12.1 can solve this exactly: [Laplace equation with robin boundary conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218266/laplace-equation-with-robin-boundary-conditions)

Comment: The method therein won't help. OP's equation is a **non-standard** Laplace equation whose coefficient is special. Please read user21's answer above carefully for more detail.