# why Mathematica gives zero as eigenvalue for $y''+\lambda y=0$ for these boundary conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to verify my hand solution using Mathematica for this problem

$$
     y^{\prime\prime}+\lambda y=0
$$

The domain is $0<x<L$ and the boundary conditions are

\begin{align*}
y(0)+y^{\prime}(0)&=0\\
y(L)+y^{\prime}(L)&=0
\end{align*}

My hand solution gives these eigenvalues

$$
\lambda=\left\{  -1,\frac{\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{4\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac
{9\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{16\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\cdots\right\}
$$

Mathematica agrees with the above, but it also claims zero is an eigenvalue

$$
\lambda=\left\{  -1,0,\frac{\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{4\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac
{9\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{16\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\cdots\right\}
$$

Which I think is wrong. zero should not be an eigenvalue.

The question is: Is Mathematica result wrong? Am I reading Mathematica output wrong?

### Mathematica output

```
ClearAll[L0, x, y, lam];
bc = {y'[0] + y[0] == 0, y'[L0] + y[L0] == 0};
Assuming[L0 > 0 && Element[lam, Reals], 
 DSolve[{y''[x] + lam y[x] == 0, bc}, y[x], x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem that I see is $n\geq 0$ in the above. Using the above result:

```
 tab1 = Table[(4*n^2*Pi^2)/L0^2, {n, 0, 4}];    
 tab2 = Table[(Pi^2 + 4*n*Pi^2 + 4*n^2*Pi^2)/L0^2, {n, 0, 4}]; 
 Union[tab1,tab2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see zero eigenvalue shows up, from applying it to `(4 n^2 Pi^2)/L0^2`. Mathematica result will match my hand solution if it said  $n>0$ for `(4 n^2 Pi^2)/L0^2` and said $n\geq 0$ for the second part `(Pi^2 + 4 n Pi^2 + 4 n^2 Pi^2)/L0^2`:

```
tab1 = Table[(4*n^2*Pi^2)/L0^2, {n, 1, 4}]; (*fixed. make it start from 1*)
tab2 = Table[(Pi^2 + 4*n*Pi^2 + 4*n^2*Pi^2)/L0^2, {n, 0, 4}]; 
Union[tab1,tab2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 11.2 on windows 7.

### Update

TO answer comment below, Here is the hand solution. The question was just misunderstanding on my part reading result of `DSolve`, since $\lambda=0$ can not be an eigenvalue, but it also showed there in the solution to `DSolve`, so I was asking why.

But `DSolve` is allowed to return trivial solution $y(x)=0$ which is not allowed when finding the eigenvalues. Lesson of the day: Use `DEigenvalues` to find eigenvalues instead of `DSolve`.

```
NDEigenvalues[{-y''[x]+NeumannValue[-y[x],x==1]+NeumannValue[y[x],x==0]},y[x],{x,0,1},6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
L0=1;
tab1=Table[ n^2 Pi^2/L0,{n,{1,2,3,4,5}}]//N;
Join[{-1},tab1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Hand solution**

Assume the solution is $y=Ae^{rx}$, then the characteristic equation is

\begin{align*}
r^{2}+\lambda & =0\\
r  & =\pm\sqrt{-\lambda}
\end{align*}

Assuming $\lambda<0$

In this case $-\lambda$ is positive and hence $\sqrt{-\lambda}$ is also
positive. Let $\sqrt{-\lambda}=\mu$ where $\mu>0$. Hence the roots are $\pm
\mu$. This gives the solution

$$
y=c_{1}\cosh\left(  \mu x\right)  +c_{2}\sinh\left(  \mu x\right)
$$

Hence

$$
y^{\prime}=\mu c_{1}\sinh\left(  \mu x\right)  +\mu c_{2}\cosh\left(  \mu
x\right)
$$

Left B.C. gives

\begin{equation}
0=c_{1}+\mu c_{2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Right B.C. gives

\begin{align*}
0 &  =c_{1}\cosh\left(  \mu L\right)  +c_{2}\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  +\mu
c_{1}\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  +\mu c_{2}\cosh\left(  \mu L\right)  \\
&  =\cosh\left(  \mu L\right)  \left(  c_{1}+\mu c_{2}\right)  +\sinh\left(
\mu L\right)  \left(  c_{2}+\mu c_{1}\right)
\end{align*}

Using (1) in the above, it simplifies to

$$
0=\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  \left(  c_{2}+\mu c_{1}\right)
$$

But from (1) again, we see that $c_{1}=-\mu c_{2}$ and the above becomes

\begin{align*}
0 &  =\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  \left(  c_{2}-\mu\left(  \mu c_{2}\right)
\right)  \\
&  =\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  \left(  c_{2}-\mu^{2}c_{2}\right)  \\
&  =c_{2}\sinh\left(  \mu L\right)  \left(  1-\mu^{2}\right)
\end{align*}

But $\sinh\left(  \mu^{2}L\right)  \neq0$ since $\mu^{2}L\neq0$ and so either
$c_{2}=0$ or $\left(  1-\mu^{2}\right)  =0$. $c_{2}=0$ results in trivial
solution, therefore $\left(  1-\mu^{2}\right)  =0$ or $\mu^{2}=1$ but $\mu
^{2}=-\lambda$, hence $\lambda=-1$ is the eigenvalue.

Corresponding eigenfunction is

$$
y=c_{1}\cosh\left(  x\right)  +c_{2}\sinh\left(  x\right)
$$

Using (1) the above simplifies to

\begin{align*}
y  & =-\mu c_{2}\cosh\left(  x\right)  +c_{2}\sinh\left(  x\right)  \\
& =c_{2}\left(  -\mu\cosh\left(  x\right)  +\sinh\left(  x\right)  \right)
\end{align*}

But $\mu=\sqrt{-\lambda}=1$, hence the eigenfunction is

$$
\fbox{$y\left(  x\right)  =c_2\left(  -\cosh\left(  x\right)  +\sinh\left(
x\right)  \right)  $}
$$

Assuming $\lambda=0$

Solution now is

$$
y=c_{1}x+c_{2}
$$

Therefore

$$
y^{\prime}=c_{1}
$$

Left B.C. $0=y\left(  0\right)  +y^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  $ gives

\begin{equation}
0=c_{2}+c_{1} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Right B.C. $0=y\left(  L\right)  +y^{\prime}\left(  L\right)  $ gives

\begin{align*}
0 &  =\left(  c_{1}L+c_{2}\right)  +c_{1}\\
0 &  =c_{1}\left(  1+L\right)  +c_{2}
\end{align*}

But from (2) $c_{1}=-c_{2}$ and the above becomes

\begin{align*}
0  &  =-c_{2}\left(  1+L\right)  +c_{2}\\
0  &  =-c_{2}L
\end{align*}

Which means $c_{2}=0$ and therefore the trivial solution. Therefore
$\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Assuming $\lambda>0$

Solution is
\begin{equation}
y=c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}x\right)  \tag{A}
\end{equation}

Hence

$$
y^{\prime}=-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{1}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
+\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
$$

Left B.C. gives

\begin{equation}
0=c_{1}+\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Right B.C. gives

\begin{align*}
0  &  =c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  +c_{2}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  -\sqrt{\lambda}c_{1}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}L\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right) \\
&  =\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  c_{1}+\sqrt{\lambda}
c_{2}\right)  +\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  c_{2}-\sqrt
{\lambda}c_{1}\right)
\end{align*}

Using (3) in the above, it simplifies to

$$
0=\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  c_{2}-\sqrt{\lambda}
c_{1}\right)
$$

But from (3), we see that $c_{1}=-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}$. Therefore the above
becomes
\begin{align*}
0  &  =\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  c_{2}-\sqrt{\lambda}\left(
-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\right)  \right) \\
&  =\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  c_{2}+\lambda c_{2}\right) \\
&  =c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  \left(  1+\lambda\right)
\end{align*}

Only choice for non trivial solution is either $\left(  1+\lambda\right)  =0$
or $\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  =0$. But $\left(  1+\lambda\right)
=0$ implies $\lambda=-1$ but we said that $\lambda>0$. Hence other choice is
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)   &  =0\\
\sqrt{\lambda}L  &  =n\pi\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots\\
\lambda_{n}  &  =\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots
\end{align*}

The above are the eigenvalues. The corresponding eigenfunction is from (A)

$$
y=c_{1_{n}}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  +c_{2_{n}}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
$$

But $c_{1_{n}}=-\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}c_{2_{n}}$ and the above becomes

\begin{align*}
y\left(  x\right)   &  =-\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}c_{2_{n}}\cos\left(  \sqrt
{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  +c_{2}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \\
&  =C_{n}\left(  -\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
+\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \right)
\end{align*}

Summary

Eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$ with eigenfunction $y\left(  x\right)  =c_{2}\left(
-\cosh\left(  x\right)  +\sinh\left(  x\right)  \right)  $ and eigenvalues
$\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2},n=1,2,3,\cdots$ with
eigenfunctions $C_{n}\left(  -\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)  +\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \right)  $. Listing the
eigenvalues in order:

$$
\lambda=\left\{  -1,\frac{\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{4\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac
{9\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\frac{16\pi^{2}}{L^{2}},\cdots\right\}
$$

Comment: "but it also claims zero is an eigenvalue" No, it doesn't. It just claims when $\lambda=0$, the BVP has a solution. If one wants to find the eigenvalue, `DEigenvalues` in principle can be used, but something like `DEigenvalues[{-y''[x] + NeumannValue[-y[x], x == 1] + NeumannValue[y[x], x == 0]}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}, 5]` doesn't work, `NDEigenvalues` works, though…

Comment: @xzczd Ok, thanks. I am used to using `DSolve` as above to find the eigenvalues since it is easier to use than the syntax of `DEigenvalues`, but I did not realize that the trivial solution will be also given by `DSolve`. This was the confusing part for me. So I should switch to `DEigenvalues` from now on to check my solution.

Comment: I agree `NeumannValue` is somewhat hard to use. (You may want to read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147155/1871). ) Hope `DEigenvalues` etc. will be more flexible and powerful in future versions.

Comment: A simple reminder that for an eigenvalue you have to have a nonzero eigenvector would have been enough.  Just a brain fart. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The `\underline{Summary}` makes me believe the details were already written before :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value `lambda = 0` simply corresponds to the most trivial solution, but Mathematica never claims it to be an eigenvalue: it only claims that it's a possible solution to the differential equation you put into `DSolve`. There's no real reason why `DSolve` shouldn't give you the trivial solution.