# Laplace equation with robin boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I want to solve the following steady state heat transfer problem with robin boundary condition at the bottom:

[image]

The following is the code for the transient solution, but how should I change the code for the steady state solution?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
<< NDSolve`FEM`
L = 100;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.6;
region = Rectangle[{-L/2, -L/2}, {L/2, L/2}];
bmesh = ToElementMesh[region];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y] - D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
    NeumannValue[a*u[x, y, t], y == -L/2] + NeumannValue[0., x == -L/2],
    u[x, L/2, t] == b,u[L/2, y, t] == 0,u[x, y, 0] == 0.
    }, u, {x, y} \[Element] bmesh, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y, 10], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: There is a [Heat Transfer model tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#509267359) and a few [application example models](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html#706049171)

Comment: @user21 Thanks for letting me know the tutorial and examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Using DSolve

V 12.1 can solve this exactly.

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
L0 = 100;
a = 1/10;
b = 6/10;
leftSide = Derivative[1, 0][u][0, y] == 0;
rightSide = u[L0, y] == 0;
bottomSide = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == a*u[x, 0];
topSide = u[x, L0] == b;
bc = {leftSide, rightSide, bottomSide, topSide};
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}];
sol0 = sol /. K[1] -> n
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*more terms makes it more accurate*)
sol1 = u[x, y] /. First@(sol0 /. Infinity -> 200); 

Plot3D[Activate[sol1], {x, 0, L0}, {y, 0, L0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Using FEM

```
Clear["Global`*"]
<< NDSolve`FEM`
L = 100;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.6;
region = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}]
bmesh = ToElementMesh[region]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But triangle elements can be more accurate

```
bmesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, L}], "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == NeumannValue[a*u[x, y], y == 0] , 
    u[x, L] == b, u[L, y] == 0}, u, {x, y} \[Element] bmesh, 
   Method -> "FiniteElement"];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A great answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps a lot.

Comment: I just noticed that the FEM solution at the bottom is smaller than zero which is not reasonable. I tried to refine the mesh, but it does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jiangming  I moved `NeumannValue` to the right side of `==` in the PDE specification. Now it matches OK the analytical. Also changed the mesh to triangles, I think it is more accurate, at least that what I would expect.

Comment: @Nasser, you could compare the solutions for the quad and triangle mesh with the analytical solution. That would tell you which one is more accurate the this problem, given the same number of elements or better the same number of degrees of freedom (`Length[mesh["Coordinates"]]`)

Comment: @Nasser When I try to export the analytical solution by using ```data = Table[{x, y, Activate[sol1]}, {x, 0, L0}, {y, 0, L0}] ```, it does not give me explicit values. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jiangming it works for me on V 12.1  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6xUmY.png)  and the full values ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cSnF8.png)