# PDE solving for two different regions?

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have searched and read all previous questions but cannot get my head around this. I am new to mathematica.
I have two regions in 2D where I want to solve PDE. Of the form:

```
Eqn=Laplacian[u[x,y], {x,y} - (alpha)u[x,y] == 0
```

Where alpha is equal to zero in one region (reduces to Laplace's eq) and equal to a constant (call it *a* so *alpha=a*). 
The regions are defined:

```
Omega = Rectangle[{100, 100}, {200, 101}];
Gamma = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {300, 200}];
Stigma = RegionDifference[Gamma, Omega];
```

So we have a narrow rectangle inside a much bigger rectangle. The ends of the inner rectange are equal to 1 and the outer borders are 0 as:

```
BCond1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1., 
 x == 100 && 100 <= y <= 101 || 
 x == 200 && 100 <= y <= 101;
BCond2 = u[x, 0] == u[x, 200] == u[0, y] == u[300, y] == 0;
```

And my question, how do I solve for *alpha=0* outside the inner box, i.e region *Stigma* and *alpha=a=3.14*(Example) inside the inner box, region *Omega* ? I have read loads of answers regarding this and it seems to stem on the *Inactive* func but can't for the life of me work out the notation or what exactly it is doing?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `The ends of the inner rectangle are equal to 1` you only give B.C. for the left and right ends. What about the B.C. for top and bottom edges of the inner rectangle?

Answer (score 5):

The following example under [PeriodicBoundaryCondition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicBoundaryCondition.html#1509320086) should get you close.  For example,

```
{length, height, xc, yc} = {300, 200, 0, 0};
{sx, sy, fx, fy} = {0, 0, length, height};
{srcxmin, srcxmax, srcymin, srcymax} = {100, 200, 100, 101};
{srcxmean, srcymean} = {(srcxmin + srcxmax)/2, (srcymin + srcymax)/2};
Ω = Rectangle[{sx, sy}, {fx, fy}];
source = If[srcxmin <= x <= srcxmax && srcymin <= y <= srcymax, 1., 
   0.];
op = ( Inactive[
      Div][({{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}]) - source;
pde = op == 0;
dc = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{pde, dc}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω];
ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Tim, many thanks for your reply. Could you possibly explain in more detail the lines: `op = ( Inactive[
      Div][({{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}]) - source;`. More specifically what does the Inactive bit do? I've seen it many times and read the doc but I do not understand the syntax/what it is doing.

Comment: You don't actually use `PeriodicBoundaryCondition ` here though??

Comment: @chris Correct.  I did not use the `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` here.  I felt the non-BC parts (the operator and source terms) of the documented case were re-usable and that I would modify/experiment the boundary conditions.

Comment: @BloodSexMagik When possible, I try to cast my problem into coefficient form as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).  I find this format to be useful when comparing between other solvers.  If you wanted to apply a Robin condition, you would need to convert to the Laplacian to coefficient form as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147155/61809).  `Inactive` simplifies adjustment of c matrix [Formal Differential Equations](https://wolfram.com/xid/0l2dr3m3kowkmft2kv6cvtalu635w4q6ys-yp7d19).

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is a great place to get started, for example see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#938383864), [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#657957277) or [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#180054820).

To get you started you can use:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Omega = Rectangle[{100, 100}, {200, 101}];
Gam = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {300, 200}];
Stigma = RegionDifference[Gam, Omega];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[Stigma, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
    "RegionMarker" -> {{{150, 100.5}, 1, 0.25}, {{1, 1}, 2, 
       20}}])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == 1]]
```

[image]

```
BCond1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1., 
   x == 100 && 100 <= y <= 101 || x == 200 && 100 <= y <= 101];
BCond2 = u[x, 0] == u[x, 200] == u[0, y] == u[300, y] == 0;
if = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     If[ElementMarker == 1, Pi, 0]*u[x, y] == 0, BCond1, BCond2}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I am having trouble though. I have traced it back to an issue with RegionDifference. It seems that it is not computing the region correctly? If I plot the resulting region with `RegionPlot[Stigma]` then I get a 2 by 2 square, not at all what I expect! I have also tried in a seperate notebook with a variety of rectangles and get the same issue. Do you know of this? I am using 11.2. Thanks

Comment: @BloodSexMagik, you could try to make use of `ToBoundaryMesh` to get a region with the internal region. Have a look at the documentation.